# CreateIndex with searchable nested object arrays

Tags: faunadb

Anyone knows how I can create an index where the term is a ref and is searchable through a nested object in an array?

In the collection "conversations" I have saved the following example data:

```
{
  "created": Time("2019-09-29T22:11:01.493034Z"),
  "updated": Time("2019-09-29T22:11:01.493034Z"),
  "participants": [
    {
      "ref": Ref(Collection("users"), "244754936642929163"),
      "firstname": "John",
      "creator": true
    },
    {
      "ref": Ref(Collection("users"), "244517629884105216"),
      "firstname": "Max"
    }
  ]
}
```

It would be great to have an index, where I can search if a ref is included in the participants array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved using an index with the array being selected as a term. When an field targeted as a term is an array a separate index entry is generated *per* item in the array. So assuming extant collections `parent` and `child` then

```
db> CreateIndex({name: "cs", source: Collection("parent"), terms: [{field: ["data", "child"]}]})
{
  ref: Index("cs"),
  ts: 1569831659780000,
  active: true,
  serialized: true,
  name: 'p',
  source: Collection("parent"),
  terms: [ { field: [ 'data', 'child' ] } ],
  partitions: 1
}
```

will do the business. Example usage:

```
db> Create(Collection("child"), {})
{
  ref: Ref(Collection("child"), "244918886014648845"),
  ts: 1569831701200000
}
db> Create(Collection("child"), {})
{
  ref: Ref(Collection("child"), "244918887478460941"),
  ts: 1569831702590000
}
db> Create(Collection("parent"), {data:{child:[Ref(Collection("child"), "244918886014648845"), Ref(Collection("child"), "244918887478460941")]}})
{
  ref: Ref(Collection("parent"), "244918956982272520"),
  ts: 1569831768880000,
  data: {
    child: [
      Ref(Collection("child"), "244918886014648845"),
      Ref(Collection("child"), "244918887478460941")
    ]
  }
}
db> Paginate(Match(Index("cs"), Ref(Collection("child"), "244918886014648845")))
{
  data: [
    Ref(Collection("parent"), "244918956982272520")
  ]
}
```

Either child ref would have matched.